# GPIO is not giving maximum 3v3 output

Tags: breadboard, dc-motor, voltage

I have a raspberry pi model B, NO B+ OR 2B, jus the model B. I am using it as a brain for a robot but I’m having a little trouble with the motors. I am using the GPIO pins to power it but when I set the output to high, I get under the required 3.3 volts. It’s no the motor because it works on the 3v3 pin. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The GPIO pins deliver nearly no current, you can't use them to drive a motor. Perhaps investigate a motor controller driven by the GPIO but supplied by a suitable power source for your motors load.

Comment: You run the risk of destroying your Pi if you connect motor leads direct to the GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I could use a transistor. To all the people like me, just use a transistor and connect the + to a 5v or 3v3 pin.